# How can I link a set of "Services Performed" to my employees in a mySQL database?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I currently have an employee database that will display employee contact info on our website.  I also have a database of all of the services our company offers.  Each employee does one or more of those particular services.  How could I link each employee to the different services they perform?

Answer (score 2):

You would add a third table as a Join table that will contain keys to the employee and service table entries.  Each employee may have several rows in the join table depending on the number of services they provide.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table

Comment: @Jordan: Do you see that green check mark next to each answer? You should click the one next to the answer you think best at some point, in addition to clicking the up arrows next to any answers you find helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can:

```
CREATE TABLE `employees_services`(
    `employee_id` INT NOT NULL ,
    `service_id` INT NOT NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY (`employee_id`, `service_id`)
)
```

and then when you need all of the services for an employee:

```
SELECT * FROM `employees` AS e
INNER JOIN `employees_services` AS es ON e.id = es.employee_id
WHERE ...
```

or when you need to all the employees for a service:

```
SELECT * FROM `services` AS s
LEFT JOIN `employees_services` AS es ON s.id = es.service_id
WHERE ..
```

.

Comment: @Jordan the up arrow is another way to say "This answer is helpful" :-D